# Не приходит письмо!

Tags: email, ajax, php, post

Ребята, подскажите, почему не приходит письмо. **Передача данных производится через ajax методом пост**, но по непонятной мне причине **ответ в виде письма так и не приходит**. Почему?

```
$name = $_POST['name'];  
$phone = $_POST['phone'];  
$time = $_POST['time'];  
$day = $_POST['day'];  
$to = "gglike@bk.ru"; /*Укажите ваш адрес электоронной почты*/  
$headers = 'Пришел новый заказ';  
$subject = "Conell";  
$message = "Имя клиента: $name \n Номер телефона: $phone\n День: $day \Удобное время для клиента: $time \n";  
$send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  
if ($send == 'true'){  
echo 'Ваш заказ принят! Большое спасибо.';  
}  
else{  
echo 'Ошибка. Сервер не может обработать запрос!';  
}
```

Comment: Потому что mail отправляет письмо, но не проверяет его приемку (это невозможно). Скорее всего, неправильно настроен почтовый сервер.

Comment: @Etki я делал все по примеру. Скажите, где настраивается почтовый сервер. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, сервер не обрабатывал мой запрос! Как и говорил [[@Etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki), нужно настраивать почтовую службу на сервере. 
Все **материалы** всегда есть **на хостинге в разделе "помощь"**.

Но я сделал так:

Первое: зашел в php.ini и исправил параметр `sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domen.ru"`  
Второе: почистил логи в `mail.log` - и вуаля - все заработало.

Кстати, [[@mJeevas](/users/31906/mjeevas)](/users/31906/mjeevas), исправь свой ответ на комментарии, он неверен, иначе я поставлю - 
специально для тебя скину даже весь код обработчик!

Вот код обработчика:

```
   header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");    
$to = "gglike@bk.ru"; //получатель уведомлений  
$HTTP_HOST = parse_url ("http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);   
$HTTP_HOST = str_replace (array ("http://","www."), "", $HTTP_HOST["host"]);  
$from = "noreply@".$HTTP_HOST;  
    $title = "Conell: обратный звонок";
$title = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($title)."?=";

$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
$headers.= "Conell: Принят заказ <".$from.">\r\n";

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$day = $_POST['day'];

$message = "Имя клиента: $name \r\n Номер телефона: $phone\r\n День: $day \Удобное время для клиента: $time \r\n";  
/*var_dump (mail ($to, $title, $message, $headers));*/
if(mail ($to, $title, $message, $headers) == true ){
    echo 'Сообщение отправлено!';
}
else{
    echo 'Ошибка! Сервер не может обработать скрипт';
}
```